# #DIV/0! error, SSIS 2010 - EXCEL 2013 - formating issue

Tags: excel, ssis

I am getting a calculation #DIV/0! error

I am inserting data from SSIS 2010 to excel 2013

the number is showing as

7, 10, 8, 11

cell is formatted as General, and output column as WSTR in SSIS

I just want an average of the cells, I.E =AVERAGE(D28:O28)but it showing #DIV/0!

any ideas how to resolve please team

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. So please provide that minimums. Did you try to check that the numbers are real numbers and not text? `7` and `'7` are shown like 7 but the first one is a number on General and the second one text

Comment: the cell is converting itself to text from general, as soon as number hits the cell , is there a way of resolving this please

Comment: #DIV/0! error on an average is due to a non valid data. If just a few of your data are numbers, `AVERAGE` will work on the ones that are numbers. When it becomes #DIV/0! is because there are no items -> `SUM(D28:O28)/0`. Check your data and range... if they are numbers, you will get an average.

Comment: Hi - I have tried the =SUM(D28:O28)/0  and still getting the #DIV/0!, there must be a way to stop ssis / excel converting the cell to text..?

Comment: Sorry, you are not getting the point. `AVERAGE` is reporting #DIV/0! error because there is no elements on the average function. So in a normal situation, this function will sum all the values on the range and divide by the number of items... If the items are not valid data, when you make a sum, there is no value and when you are dividing by then valid number of data (0), then the #DIV/0! appears, because you got `Anything/0`. So check the data in your range.

Comment: 7, 10, 8, 11, they are the numbers in the cells...its because they are text. and I need to stop ssis converting the cell from general to text when the number hits the cell..but I don't know hoe to correct this . do you know how to correct this error please? sorry to ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201199/discussion-between-david-garcia-bodego-and-joeysonic).

Comment: Joeysonic you've got 25 questions on this site and only 96 reputation. You could really stand to improve the quality of your posts here. It would make it a lot easier for you to get answers, rather then spending your entire day in chat on stackoverflow trying to get people to write code for you... you could make a solid question with formatting and include your code (per the site recommendations) and not spend hours doing the chat thing. You should be doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for every question.

Answer (score 0):

in SSIS you can change the output datatype to DT_NUMERIC instead of DT_WSTR, this way Excel will recognize that the data loaded from SSIS is numeric instead of text.

Comment: Hi I have tried this and it did not work. I did try conversion fields too with no joy

Answer (score 0):

As excel always when in putting from SSIS, you need to place query to point to row above

SQL - D28:O28

this to go into row D29:029 in Excel

you have to format the row above and below as number, then the data will flow in, without excel defaulting to text

finally cracked it x